# Firebase rule to access own data, public data or specific data only

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

i want to achieve the following with a firebase rule and firebase-queries. (I am using firestore and vuejs)

Precondition: The user has to be auth logged in in any case

1. The user is allowed to `read/write` all of his own created data-entries
2. The user is allowed to `read` all data which has a field (in my case `"visibility"`) set to `"public"`
3. The user is allowed to read specific entries if he has the `id` of an entry even if the entry's `"visibility"` field is set to unequal `"public"` (e.g. `"private"`)

Let's assume this are the entries of my collection

First entry created from User-A and the second from User-B and the third from User-C:

So:

1. User-B should be allowed to `read/write` the second entry (and so on for the other users)
2. User-A,B,C should be allowed to `read` the first and the third entry.
3. User-A,C should be allowed to `read` the second entry if they know the firebase document's ID via direct document-id query or so. like `db.collection('my_collection').doc('abcxyz').get()`

Second question would be: Do i even need the field `"user_id"` to be able to filter the request based on user-created documents? Or does firebase has a built-in functionality to retrieve self-created documents based on (authentication) ?

```
[
  {
    "user_id": "the User-A's firebase id",
    "foo": "foo",
    "bar": true,
    "visibility": "public"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "the User-B's firebase id",
    "foo": "foo",
    "bar": true,
    "visibility": "private"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "the User-C's firebase id",
    "foo": "foo",
    "bar": true,
    "visibility": "public"
  }
]
```

Can somebody help me with creating the rule(s) and the requests? (i am using this npm [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase))

this is the query i have right now for retrieving self-created entries

```
this.db.collection("my_collection").where('user_uid','==',this.$store.state.user.id).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        //do something 
      });
    });
```

and this for creating

```
db.collection("my_collection").add({
    user_uid: this.$store.state.user.id,
    foo: this.foo,
    bar: this.bar,
    visibilty: this.visibility
  })
```

and this is the rule i have until now

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore does not automatically associate documents with the user that causes their creation. If you need such metadata, you'll need to store it in each document as you do now.

To ensure that a user can only read their own documents, you need two things:

1. A query that only tries to read those documents. You have this already, so ☑.
2. Rules that allow the query, but reject broader reads.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data. user_uid;
    }
  }
}
```

For more on this, also see the documentation on [securely querying data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query).

---

To allow the other use cases, you'll need to expand the rules to allow that access too in a similar way. But you'll need to execute a separate query for each case, as Firestore queries can't contain OR type conditions on multiple fields and that is what your use-case requires.

Comment: Thank you very much